# How can I resize an image in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to resize an image which will then be exported and saved by the user.  I've tried the following methods but neither of them are working for me.

The first method is to set the scaleX and scaleY.  This does cause the image to be resized within the page, but doesn't seem to truly resize the image.  In other words, it is being displayed at the proper size but the image data hasn't changed.

```
img.set({
    scaleX: newWidth/currentWidth,
    scaleY: newHeight/currentHeight
    });
```

The other method I tried was using the resize filter.  Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to do anything.  The other filters I'm using are working fine.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
    resizeType: 'hermite',
    scaleX: newWidth/currentWidth,
    scaleY: newHeight/currentHeight
}));
img.applyFilters();
canvas.requestRenderAll();
```

If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it.

Comment: But how are you exporting it? the resize filter is indeed resizing the image.

Comment: I use toDataURL().  The export doesn't seem to be the problem.  I am looking at the img.width and img.height properties before and after executing applyFilters() and they are not changing.

Comment: They could even not change, but if you look at Image._element.width and image._element.height before and after filter, you will notice they change.

If you want to export the image ONLY, do image._element.toDataUrl(), you will get the canvas data of the canvas representing the resized image.

Also consider that if you have not disabled webgl, you are actually using lanzcos.

Comment: Ok, yes, I'm seeing the image._element.width and image._element.height with the new dimensions.  What is image.width and image.height?  Is that just the size that it's being displayed at?  What''s the difference between image._element, image._filteredEl, and image.originalElement?

Comment: Is long for a comment but is the different stage of caching. Normally you have onlt _element and _originalElement, unless you add filters AND resize filter together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to obtain the resized image from image._element.toDataURL() rather than calling image.toDataURL().